# jQuery GetCity is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating cascading dropdownlist but i got a error with that:

```
function GetCity(_warehousesId) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#ddlcity").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Carriage/GetCityByStaeId";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { warehousesid: _warehousesId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>Select City</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            $("#ddlcity").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });

};
```

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateModel, new  SelectList(Model.StateModel, "WarehousesID", "Name"), new { @id = "ddlstate", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })
<br />
<br />
<select id="ddlcity" name="ddlcity" style="width: 200px"></select>

<br /><br />
}
```

And all time I get an error: "GetCity is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why was this declared twice `var url = "/Carriage/GetCityByStaeId";
var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";` ??

Comment: Remove name from self-executing function, otherwise it will not work. `(function ($) {/* .. */})(jQuery);`. Also you are passing `jQuery` lib as `_warehouseId`

Comment: Use separate `<script>` block, it can't have both content and `src`

Comment: i change that, now i got error " $ is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

Your `(function GetCity(_warehousesId) {})(jQuery)` is wrong. You try to create self-executing function and later you try to use it.

it should be just `function GetCity(_warhouseId) {}` to be able to execute it later.

---

If `<script>` has `src` attribute, than any content inside will be ignored. Have different tags for jQuery and for your code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function GetCity(_warehousesId) {}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Use another script block for your jQuery script and define the function `GetCity` properly

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var url = "/Carriage/GetCityByStaeId";
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    function GetCity(_warehousesId) {
       //Your code
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I sorry is my fault. By chance I've added them there, anyway it does not work for me

Comment: I do this, but i got :" $ is not a function"

Comment: @MikeEvans, You are referencing `jquery-ui` library. You need to add reference to jQuery library, use as I have provide in answer